# EMC shielded box with transparent window?

Tags: emc, enclosure

Is there such a thing? I would like to put my board in a box to isolate it from radiated emissions externally and also limit emissions from the board to the outside. I would also like a transparent window. Is this possible? [Thinking conductive coating, fine mesh etc]

Comment: Ever had a look into a microwave oven?

Comment: Yes - which is why I had the idea. However, I do not recall seeing such boxes for circuit boards on the major site eg RS, Farnell, Digikey etc

Comment: You were just asking if such a thing exists. If you want to ask for some shopping advice, this is offtopic here. Not hard to build one yourself though

Comment: Does such a box exist? because "Put your circuit board in the microwave oven" is not a suitable answer. Nor is making one myself given the cost of my time.

Comment: Pay someone else to do it? I doubt those things exist as ots boxes where you can put anything in, but a lot of equipment is build that way, e.g. many network analyzers I had in hands. And if you need just one, its not a big job to cut a hole into some existing shielded box and glue some mesh over it.

Comment: You could get an enclosure with a window and cover the window with a conductive transparency - that amount of effort does not seem large. Not sure how widespread these are in distribution.

Comment: The difference between making and buying would probably be that I would get some specifications with the latter as regards EMC.

Comment: Google "Indium tin oxide coated glass".

Comment: Wire mesh will be cheaper than ITO.